# Python Video Streaming - Stream ends prematurely at 0, should be

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I am working on a plate recognition software with python OpenCV in Windows, which I need to get stream from Raspberry Pi camera.

I made ready Raspberry Pi to stream video fram camera and get it with my software. But usually I got error and my stream is over. I tried to auto reconnect when that error happens. Then, software works correctly after error if error happens at the beginning. If error happens during software run, CPU usage of my software going high and not responding. Just to be sure, I tried to get stream with VLC player. Sometimes, I could not get it. If I could get stream, there was no error happen. In some of my research, I found that the error occurred because Raspberry Pi stopped streaming. But I made sure that Raspberry Pi kept streaming.

```
import time
import cv2
from imutils.video import videostream
cap = videostream.VideoStream(src='http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8160', framerate=2).start()
time.sleep(0.1)
while True:
    try:
        frame = cap.read()
        if frame is None:
            cap.stop()
            cap = videostream.VideoStream(src='http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8160', framerate=2).start()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            continue
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    except:
        cap.stop()
        cap = videostream.VideoStream(src='http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8160', framerate=2).start()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        continue
    if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I need to get stream without any error. My error like

> [http @ 000001c46ff47040] Stream ends prematurely at 0, should be 18446744073709551615
>
> warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:856)
>
> warning: http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8160 (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:857)

How do I get rid of this error?

**EDIT:**
I learn "How to stream Raspberry Pi camera to another pc" from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjPsW-7FUng)

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this error. In my opinion, check your `htop` to see RAM storage. Maybe your device don't have enough RAM. I resolved my problem by this way. Hope that it's useful.